# How to store a user's object in every routes

Tags: node.js, ejs

I set up a navbar.ejs as a partial so that i don't need to rewrite it again. Every routes require navbar.ejs. Im using passport for Auth

```
  <% if (!user) { %>
        <li><a href="/signup">Signup</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    <% } else{ %>
      <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a><%= user.profile.name %></a></li>
   <% } %>
```

Example routes

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('home');
}

app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
   res.render('dashboard', { user: req.user });
}

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
   res.render('about');
}
```

For routes that have `user's object` as the response are working fine when rendered but others will keep showing

```
user is not defined
```

I know that the obvious solution is to pass in a `user's object` in every single route, but that is really insane.

Imagine if I have to do this

```
 app.get('/1', function(req, res) {
       res.render('/1', {user: req.user});
 }
app.get('/2', function(req, res) {
       res.render('/2', {user: req.user});
    }

app.get('/3', function(req, res) {
       res.render('/3', {user: req.user});
    }

app.get('/4', function(req, res) {
       res.render('/4', {user: req.user});
    }

app.get('/5', function(req, res) {
       res.render('/5', {user: req.user});
    }
```

If routes that require authentication, I don't really mind to pass the `user's object`, but simple routes like home, about or contact I don't feel like the need to pass in.

Comment: Are you using passport for your authentication mechanism?

Comment: Yes I am using passport as my authentication

Comment: Next time please state that you are using passport or custom authentication for clarity purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to keep passing the user's object in every single route then you have to set up a middleware

somewhere after your passport configuration add the following codes

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.locals.user = req.user;
});
```

then you no longer needed to pass the user's object in every single route

```
app.get('/1', function(req, res) {
       res.render('/1');
 }
app.get('/2', function(req, res) {
       res.render('/2');
    }
```